# Can weblogic cache reponses to get requests?

Tags: caching, weblogic

I don't mean using coherence.  I am looking for a way to avoid hitting my application to look something up that I've already looked up.  When the client performs a GET on a resource I want it to hit the application the first time only and after that return a cached copy.

I think I can do this with apache and mod_mem_cache, but I was hoping there was a weblogic built in solution that I'm just not able to find.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's inbuilt features to do that across the entire app server, but if you want to do it programmatically, perhaps [CacheFilter](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2011/05/04/configuring-cachefilter-in-weblogic/) might work.